# SSL error when conecting to Memgraph using Bolt

Tags: memgraphdb

When I try to connect to Memgraphs isntance using Bolt I get the following error:

`An unknown error occurred while processing an SSL message. Please make sure that you have SSL properly configured on the server and the client.`

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Secure connections are supported and disabled by default. The server initially ships with a self-signed testing certificate located at `/etc/memgraph/ssl/`. You can use it by changing the configuration and passing its path within the following parameters:

```
--bolt-cert-file=/etc/memgraph/ssl/cert.pem
--bolt-key-file=/etc/memgraph/ssl/key.pem
```

If you are using your own certificate be sure to enter the correct path to the certificate.

To disable SSL support and use insecure connections to the database erase or make comments out of both parameters `(--bolt-cert-file` and `--bolt-key-file`) by adding a hashtag in front of them.